# iPhone App rejection audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying in my own header file class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

If I include in my own header file the method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag;
```

Will my iPhone app be rejected?

I've already submitted the binary. Do I have to reject it and resubmit, without this method in my own class header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need to put this in your header. Just import the AVFoundation headers.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

But you won' get rejected, no.

Comment: Thanks coob! I'll do that next time! And you guys are great, taking time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be to wait and see.  Just because they reject it, doesn't mean you can't make the necessary modifications and resubmit it.  It's not taking too long to push apps through the process just now anyway.

I personally don't think they will reject it - but Apple do some funny stuff sometimes...

Comment: I'm worried. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that right.  Emilio is right on both counts!  Even if he weren't though, I'd still chance my luck with any app submission - you don't lose anything for trying!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Simon! I'll leave it just like that!

Answer (score 1):

You put it there to let the compiler know you are going to use that method and that it exists and to avoid getting a warning, nothing more, the resulting executable is not gonna be different if you don't include that line.

Besides, it's a public method.

Comment: That's why I've put the method in my header, to avoid the warning. Thanks for your answer that gave me more peace of mind! I'll just leave it like that.